# What's the mechanic behind building destruction?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

Since version 0.25, the buildings of the space center can be destroyed by flying vessels into them.

What exactly are the mechanics behind building destruction? Do buildings have a hidden impact tolerance stat like parts? If yes, how high is it for each building? If no, what other mechanics decide if a building survives a collision or not?

Comment: From what I've gathered, each building had their own impact tolerance. For instance, the VAB has (one of) the highest resistance. As to actual values, I have no idea.

Answer (score 2):

Tolerance to crashing isn't based exactly on part count, its more on meters per second.
If you fly an entire rocket into the VAB, its going to do the same amount of damage as shooting a Command Module much faster.

**Examples:**
The VAB can be destroyed by the stray solid fuel booster, and the launchpad by a rocket that tips over at launch (Yes, it's possible).

As for actual  values, no-one has found them and even know's if they even exist.
So in the end, it's all about speed.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**

With the new BETA 0.90 version, we now have different building sizes because of their 'levels'
Still going to assume the same thing, still no true values given, but sizes could definitely lower their true HP.